# I want to move 100 out of 1Million files of a particular extension to a target folder in linux

Tags: shell

I have a folder(/DIR/SRC) containing 1 Million files with different types of extensions.
I would like to pick a particular extension files from the SRC folder, may be 1000 at a time and move to a target folder which is at /DIR/TGT.
The file name has the format 1234_XXXX-XXXX_TIMESTAMP.ext

Comment: You can do a "ls -1 *.ext | tail -100" for example, the tail-command shows only the first 100. You have to proceed the output in your own following script

Comment: What's the objection to a for loop?

Comment: No objection, I thought may be we could write it as compact as possible,

Comment: If you do have a resolution with for loop, I wouldn't mind that. Thank you

Comment: Which ones? Any 100? The 100 newest? The 100 oldest? The largest? The smallest? What are your file names like? Can we assume they contain no special characters? No spaces, no `*`, no newlines? What shell do you use? Some shells like zsh have nifty tools for this. Others don't. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: any 100 will do, I have to move them 100 at a time and yes the file names contains only  _ and - in between file names.also, Its a bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
mv `ls -1 *.your_ext|tail -n 100` /TARGETDIR
```

I didn't test it, but in this way it should work.

If you want the latest 100 or alphabetically the first 100 (or, or, or,...) you can change the ls-command.

Comment: invalid option -- '1', Sorry, this is not working . Thank you for your help though

Comment: The ticks in my code are backticks, I didn't know your keyboard-layout, so I can't tell you how to do this

Comment: Biber, I got the tick symbol, Thank you for that. Now the destination folder part , do I have to mention the complete path of the destination folder?

Comment: Biber, it worked, the tilt was at a wrong position in my command. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This will move all files with `.your_extension` in current folder to your new path

```
mv *.your_ext your/new/path
```

Comment: thank you, but I would like to move the first 100 files in the directory and then continue moving the next 100